# Create an activity when a marketing cloud email is sent

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, activity

How do I create an activity in salesforce account when a marketing cloud email is sent to that account?

Answer (score 2):

You can write some AMPScript in the email and use [CreateSalesforceObject](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/createsalesforceobject.htm) function to create a record in the Activity (Task/Event) object.

You must have Salesforce Marketing Cloud Connect set up as a pre-requisite